# virtualization problem

Tags: linux

I am using Virtual machine Manager on ubuntu server but can't create new virtual machien vecause have warning: KVM is noit available. This may mean the KVM package is not installed, or the KVM kernel modules are not loaded. Your virtual machines may perform poorly

Comment: Marked closed for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

It might be several things - your CPU might not support KVM, you really don't have KVM installed, etc. Take a look at the official installation instructions:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation

Also, here's a nice KVM tutorial (for Ubuntu 9.10, though):

- http://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-kvm-on-ubuntu-9.10